# Add event listener after getting radio button value

Tags: javascript, html

i want to loop through the radio input and after getting the selected button run a function on it to get value from the radio tag ... but im having problem attaching the a function to run on the selected radio

```
for(var i=0;i<removeCartItemsButtons.length; i++){
var button= removeCartItemsButtons[i]
button.addEventListener('click',removeCartItem)//**like i did here**
```

}

```js
var form= document.getElementsByClassName('product-form')[0]
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()

var selectedSize = document.getElementsByName('size')
for(var i=0;i<selectedSize.length; i++){
    var  size=selectedSize[i].checked
    size.addEventListener('change',addToCartClicked)   
}
}
```

```html
<form class="product-form">
                <div class="product-sizes">
                <input type="radio" class="size" name="size" id="size1" value="34">
                <label for="size1">34</label>
                <input type="radio" class="size" name="size" id="size2" value="36">
                <label for="size2">36</label>
                <input type="radio" class="size" name="size" id="size3" value="38">
                <label for="size3">38</label>
                <input type="radio" class="size" name="size" id="size4" value="40">
                <label for="size4">40</label>
                <input type="radio" class="size" name="size" id="size5" value="42">
                <label for="size5">42</label>
                <input type="radio" class="size" name="size" id="size6" value="44">
                <label for="size6">44</label>
                </div>

                <button class="btn-black" type="submit" >ADD TO CART</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Your form.addEventListener is missing a symbol ( } )

Comment: Why are you trying to add an event listener after the form is submitted? How is the `size` value going to change after submission? If you need to extract the `size` value after the submit button is pressed you can just pluck it from the form.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular i dont want to change the value i want to use the value to change another element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running the `submit` event handler then there's no point then in adding an event handler to an element on the form.
If you want to extract the value of a radiobutton you can do it with this one line of code:

```
    let size =  document.querySelector('input[name="temp"]:checked').value;
```

Once you have that value you can call whatever Javascript function you need:

```
function addToCartClicked(size) {
    console.log("Size: "+size);
    document.body.append(size);
}

var form = document.getElementsByClassName('product-form')[0];

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let size =  document.querySelector('input[name="temp"]:checked').value;
    addToCartClicked(size);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd need to modify your JS code like below (sorry, I added semicolon to help me read better :-)

var form = document.getElementsByClassName('product-form')[0];

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var selectedSize = document.getElementsByName('size');
    for(var i=0; i<selectedSize.length; i++){
        var size=selectedSize[i].checked;
        if(size === true) {
          selectedSize[i].addEventListener('change', addToCartClicked);   
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: it isnt running addToCartClicked Function

Comment: Sorry, I may not have understood your question. Can you elaborate on what do you mean when you say it isn't running the addToCartClicked function? Did you mean to execute it? I had excluded that from my code. I guess, what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

- I don't know why you want to add event after the form is already submitted but anyway you can check for selected element and add your event
- when the index of selected element come the size result will be true so you can add your event now
- also you was added the event to `size` var who it `true` or `false` not for the input element
- i changed your `change` event with `click`

> Here's your code

```
var form= document.getElementsByClassName('product-form')[0]
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var selectedSize = document.getElementsByName('size');
    for(var i=0; i<selectedSize.length; i++) {
        var size= selectedSize[i].checked;
        if(size) { 
            selectedSize[i].addEventListener('click',addToCartClicked);
        } 
    }
});

function addToCartClicked() {
    document.body.append(this.value);
}
```

Comment: it isnt running addToCartClicked Function

Comment: It's will run when you click on the choosed input after submit the form that's why i said at the first i don't know why you want to add event after the form is submitted - i think that you need to execute a function depending on the value of the input at this case you don't need to add event and also at this case the problem will be with you because you don't know what you want to do and you are not clear enough about that all you said is that you just want to add event so that event will be added after click on submit button then you should click on choosed input to fire the event